# Is this valid html?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="main" 
     style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#FFFFFF; height:400px; width:500px;" 
     onclick="location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';"></div>
```

I'm just trying to make it so when click anywhere in the div it acts like a link and takes to a new page. It works, just asking if it is clean/valid. Thanks! ( i left out the first and last < > so it would display here).

Comment: What does http://validator.w3.org/ say?

Comment: It won't work without JavaScript. Otherwise, it's okay (although a purist would put the `onclick` event into a separate script block)

Comment: I added the `<` and `>` back in

Comment: Yes, it is valid HTML however if you really want to do it right you should move the css declarations to a separate .css file and add the onclick event handler dynamically that way you would have complete separation of content and presentation

Comment: Ok i'll separate the onclick event handler and style. For this thing if someone doesn't have javascript its not too bad. How to add the onclick dynamically? Btw shouldn't these be answers not comments.

Comment: The absolute simplest way would be to import jQuery and use the click() method, so you could write something like this $('.main').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});

Comment: OK, moved my comments to an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You don’t actually need the `<div>`, you can just adapt the `<a>` element’s style so that it is displayed as a block level element by settings `display: block` for it. This would certainly be a cleaner (and arguably slightly easier) solution.

Comment: I don't see mention of an anchor tag (?)

Comment: @Keith: yea, nor do I. I was momentarily confused. But I’ve already adapted my answer – I believe the gist is still true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid HTML however if you really want to do it right you should move the css declarations to a separate .css file and add the onclick event handler dynamically that way you would have complete separation of content and presentation and apply unobtrusive DOM scripting best practices.

The absolute simplest way would be to import jQuery and use the click() method, so you could write something like this:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
  location.href='http://www.yahoo.com';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid, yes. Good practice, no. What is wrong with

```
<style>a.main { background-color:#FFFFFF; height:400px; width:500px; }</style>
<a class="main" href='http://www.yahoo.com'>...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid HTML sure, that's pretty easy, good form no.

You should not be using inline style (`style="..."`) unless [absolutely necessary](http://www.dustindiaz.com/style-with-strict/); add another class and set your styling there instead. Inline style attributes are one of the [cardinal sins](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) if web development, IMO.

You should not be using `onclick=` to assign javascript events; bind the event with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) instead. This is the correct way of doing things according to the W3C, the onclick method being deprecated, and [separates content from logic](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation).

Is there a reason you're not using an anchor (`a`) tag for this? You can make it a block element by setting `display: block;` in CSS, it's semantically better to mark up links this way, and it provides [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) if javascript is not available.